# assigning the same arrays to a list of rows

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an nx2 matrix corresponding to some x,y values and what I'd like to do is replace a subset of the 1x2 rows with some values. Currently I get that subset using find(). for instance, if I had the following matrix:

```
 k=    [1 2
        3 4
        5 6
        7 8
        9 0]
```

and I used find() on some other related 5x1 array to get say, the indices

```
indices = [1 3 5]
```

I would then like to quickly change rows 1, 3, and 5 in k to the same, predetermined row like for instance [-2 -6]. So the result would be...

```
 k=     [-2 -6
          3  4
         -2 -6
          7  8
         -2 -6]
```

I know that for an individual row I can just do k(1,:) = [-2 -6] but I can't seem to find the syntax for doing this generally to a list of rows. k(indices,:) = [-2 -6] is not a valid syntax. There is of course the two-line solution of doing it for column 1 and then column 2 but I would thing there is a compact way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that it fails because the dimensions don't match? What about k(indices;:) = [-2 -6; -2 -6; -2 -6], assuming you have 3 indices?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the size of the matrix you want to place into the old matrix is the same as the size of the elements being replaced.  In this case, `size(k(indices,:)) = [3 2]`.  Use `repmat` to generate a matrix of the appropriate size, and then the assignment will succeed.

```
replacement = [-2 -6];

k(indices,:) = repmat(replacement,length(indices),1)

k =

-2    -6
 3     4
-2    -6
 7     8
-2    -6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also repeat the row by using one-indices:

```
row = [-2 -6];
k(indices,:) = row(ones(size(indices)),:);
```